# Determine an object's runtime X-location

Tags: vb.net, location, coordinates

This might be a stupid question, but I'm attempting to move a button to the left by roughly 160 pixels each time the button is pressed. However, I need to know what the x-location is of the object at runtime so I can dynamically add those 160 pixels to it. A real world example of this would be right above (if you happen to be using chrome/firefox-which who isn't?) when the new tab button moves every time a new tab is opened (additionally subtracting those pixels too which is harder because I have to figure out how to handle the tab close event within a QTab control in the QIOS devsuite).

Comment: WinForm?  WPF?  ASP.NET?  Other?

Comment: @StevenDoggart It's WinForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Button1.Location = New Point(Button1.Location.X - 160, Button1.Location.Y)
```

or this:

```
Dim pt As Point = Button1.Location
Button1.Location = New Point(pt.X - 160, pt.Y)
```

or maybe this:

```
Dim pt As Point = Button1.Location
pt.Offset(-160, 0)
Button1.Location = pt
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the WinForm designer, each control on your form is assigned a unique name.  When you place a control on the form, the designer automatically assigns a unique name (e.g. `Button1`), but you can change it to whatever you want.  The designer automatically creates a class-level variable (i.e. field) for each control.  The name of the variable matches the name of the control.  So, for instance, if you call your control `Button1`, then you can access the X-location of that button via the `Button1` variable, like this:

```
Dim x As Integer = Button1.Left
```

If you are writing code that is intended to handle events from multiple controls, so you wouldn't know which variable to use, you can use the event handler's `sender` parameter.  Every event handler has a `sender As Object` parameter which points to the control that is raising the event.

So, for instance, in a the click event, you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub ClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
    Dim clickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim x As Integer = clickedButton.Left
End Sub
```